# php pdo return lastinsertId after mysql insert

Tags: php

I want to get the last inserted id return on a successful insert.  I have looked all over and can't seem to find the answer. I have a prepared statement that inserts properly and returns the lastinsertId if I echo.  I want to return the lastID and use it outside the method.

```
              public function insertFoul() {

            $conn = parent::connect();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO " . TBL_FOULS . " (
                      qtr,
                      f_time,
                      team,
                      foul
                    ) VALUES (
                      :qtr,
                      :f_time,
                      :team,
                      :foul
                    )";
                    try {
              $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
              $st->bindValue( ":qtr", $this->data["qtr"], PDO::PARAM_STR );
              $st->bindValue( ":f_time", $this->data["f_time"], PDO::PARAM_STR );
              $st->bindValue( ":team", $this->data["team"], PDO::PARAM_STR );
              $st->bindValue( ":foul", $this->data["foul"], PDO::PARAM_STR );

             if($st->execute()){
                  $lastID = $conn->lastInsertId();
              }
              echo $lastID;
              return $lastID;

            } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
              parent::disconnect( $conn );
              die( "Query failed: " . $e->getMessage() );
            }
          }
```

I then have a php file that calls the method.  I want to get the $lastID and use it as a variable.

PHP file:

```
if($foul->insertFoul()){
    $newId = $lastID;
}else{
    echo "No ID";
}
```

I appreciate everyones help.

Comment: You're returning it, so it'll be within the `$foul->insertFoul()` call. You're better to do, `$insertId = $foul->insertFoul(); if(!$insertId) { echo "no ID";} else { $newId = $insertId; }`. (*One more note, don't `echo` anything before you're return.*)

Comment: You could also save it to a class property instead, ie. `$this->lastID = $conn->lastInsertId();`, then you could do `if($foul->insertFoul()){ $newId = $foul->lastID; }`

Comment: Actually, do exactly what @Sean said.

Comment: Thank you Darren!  Thank you Sean!!  that did the trick.  Blessed night to both of you.